# Removing slug from custom taxanomy and custom post type by add_url_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, custom-post-type

Problem :

there is a custom taxanomy named product_category and custom post type as slug as product. Now the url seems like this.

example.com/categories/laptop

and for product post

example.com/product/laptop/acer/acerlaptopname

Now i wanted them to show like this :

example.com/laptop

and similarly

example.com/laptop/acer/acerlaptopname

Solutions tried :

1. Solution using .htaccess :

This solution didn't work because of internal wordpress url rewriting rules.

2. solution tried using add_url_rewriting:

I added following code in the functions.php and then flushed

On a first part i added this code and found that

```
example.com/laptop/acer/acerlaptopname    --> as needed
```

and

```
example.com/product/laptop/acer/acerlaptopname  --> not needed
```

both are running.

```html
add_action('init', function()
{ 

 
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?post_type=product&product_category=$matches[1]&product_brand=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]', 'top');
}, 0, 0);

?>
```

Now to remove the categories slug from cutsom taxanomy pages i added following line in the code above.

```
add_rewrite_rule('(.+)/?$', 'index.php?product_category=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

This helped me in removing slug "categories" now this url is working

```
example.com/laptop  --> as needed
```

and

```
example.com/categories/laptop --> this gives 404 as required
```

**Solution i need**

I want only

```
example.com/laptop  --> this to work

example.com/laptop/acer --> this to work

example.com/laptop/acer/laptopname --> this to work
```

Note : If you need any other information please ask in comment before putting a down vote button.